# Wireless router with repeater setup

Tags: wireless-networking, router, repeater

I have 2 netgear routers "WGR614 v6" and "WNR2000". How to set these up (one as a repeater) to get wireless access throughout my large house?

Answer (score 4):

The *WNR2000* is capable of being a repeater the *WGR614 v6* is not. So you you will use the WGR614 v6 as you main access point and set the MAC Address of that router in the wizard section mentioned below.

For the *WNR2000* you need to make the adjustments on this screen:

[image: netgear smartwizard]

Comment: To get a bigger view of this image right-click and save the image or if in Firefox right-click and choose the View Image option. :)